# Visual Studio not able to open css files anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Now I am not able to edit CSS files after I tried a few .less extensions. I have removed all extensions but still Visual Studio throws "Operation could not be completed" when i try to open file.

How can I get CSS file editing back ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Tools/Import and Export Settings - Reset all setting** fixed problem.

Comment: That still didn't fix it for me :(

Comment: @freshblood Life saviour.

Comment: That still didn't fix it for me too

Answer (score 0):

In the **Tools/Options** dialog, under **Environment/General**, click the `Restore File Associations` button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but still double click on css files throws "Operation could not be compeleted".

Comment: What is the exact and complete wording of the error message?  Include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You know... you're just working through projects and little time sink crap like this pops up. Anyway, here's a link that worked for me. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83 - Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1.